# Checking variable for multiple inputs after onChange event

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

So I have a dynamic form that has two columns. One has a job name and the other has an input box where the user could enter their on description of the job.

```
while($install_table_r = tep_db_fetch_array($install_table_query))
{
echo'
<tr class="dataTableRow">
    <td class="dataTableContent">
        <input type="text" id="job_name" name="job_name"
        value="'.$install_table_r['name_of_job'].'" disabled />
    </td>
    <td class="dataTableContent">
        <input type="text" name="job_desc" value="'.$install_comment['comment'].'"
        onChange="insertCommentInstall(this.value,)" />
    </td>
 </tr>
';
}
```

So as you can see I have a while loop that populates this form. So it could potentially have a lot of input boxes that you can use to describe the jobs.

The issue I am having is that, when I handle this form with the AJAX I have set up. The javascript simply grabs the last job on the list and uses that as it's jobs name. So in essence it is grabbing the input box correctly it's just placing it in the wrong row.

Here is the javascript that handles this change.

```
var job = document.getElementsByNames("job_name").value;
var comment = document.getElementsByNames("job_desc").value;
var url = "<?php echo FILENAME_ORDERS_EDIT_AJAX; ?>?action=insert_comment_install&oID=<?php 
echo $_GET['oID']; ?> &new_comment=" + value + "&jobname=" + job;
```

I know I should be grabbing the elements with getElementByNames but I just don't know how to pair up the comment with the proper job that it's supposed to go with. So if someone comments next to the input box for Granite Job the comment should be paired up with the job name 'Granite Job' in the database. Instead currently it will just be paired up with the last job on the list which is 'Cabinet Assembly'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've never heard of `getElementsByNames`. This should be `getElementsByName` instead. Besides that this will return a nodelist of all selected elements to the variable `job`, meaning you'll have to use the correct index number to get the value you're looking for out it.

Comment: insertCommentInstall where is this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a HTML error for the attribute `id`
You may not in HTML standards to give a same value for `id` attribute to a multiple elements.

But fortunately we can use this unique identifier to make your code works
You can edit your PHP code to some thing like this:

```
$counter=0;
while($install_table_r = tep_db_fetch_array($install_table_query))
{
echo'
<tr class="dataTableRow">
    <td class="dataTableContent">
        <input type="text" id="job_name_'.$counter.'" 
        value="'.$install_table_r['name_of_job'].'" disabled />
    </td>
    <td class="dataTableContent">
        <input type="text" id="job_desc_'.$counter.'" value="'.$install_comment['comment'].'"
        onChange="insertCommentInstall(this.value,'.$counter.')" />
    </td>
 </tr>
';
$counter++;
}
```

You can see we added a counter to identify our rows

Updating your Javascript code will be as follow:

```
var insertCommentInstall=function(value,identifier){
    var job = document.getElementById("job_name_"+identifier).value;
    var comment = document.getElementById("job_desc_"+identifier).value;
    var url = "<?php echo FILENAME_ORDERS_EDIT_AJAX; ?>?action=insert_comment_install&oID=<?php echo $_GET['oID']; ?> &new_comment=" + value + "&jobname=" + job;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a selector like `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByTagName` you are retrieving a nodelist of all elements with the specified attribute (adding a classname to your inputs would make this easier). You need to specify one particular node out of the nodelist in order to fetch it's value. In order to retrieve all values in your nodelist you need to loop through it and [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the values of all its nodes into an array.

```
//finds all elements with classname "jobs"
var jobs = document.getElementsByClassName("jobs");

//create new array that we push all the values into
var jobValues = [];

//loop through our jobs nodelist and get the value of each input
for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length - 1; i++) {
    jobValues.push(jobs[i].value);
}

jobValues; //gives you a list of all the values you pushed into the array
jobValues[5]; //gives you the value of the 6th input you looped through
```